# Quand quelqu'un dit « Excusez-moi »

Tags: usage

Quand quelqu'un dit : « Excusez-moi »

Quelle est la réponse ?

Comment: Note that in general one would say 'pardon', excusez-moi is more of an English translation usage even though it's technically correct

Comment: Ça dépend du sens : 'excusez-moi de vous avoir écrasé le pied' ou 'excusez-moi, avez-vous l'heure' ?

Answer (score 6):

> - je vous en prie.
> - ça n'est pas grave.
> - ce n'est rien.

Comment: Liste à laquelle j'ajouterai pour ma part : *"Si je veux!"* Car je trouve aussi absurde qu'inconséquent l'usage d'un impératif dans une tournure censée être l'expression d'une politesse.

Comment: @aCOSwt > J'avais un prof qui détestait ça effectivement :-)

Answer (score 5):

On peut répondre  ou ne pas répondre, selon le cas ; on peut se contenter de sourire parfois, comme lorsque quelqu'un vous marche sur le pied bien que cela ne fasse pas sourire beaucoup de gens; dans un tel cas on peut aussi leur demander poliment de faire attention à leurs actions.

- Ça ira pour cette fois mais que ça ne se reproduise pas.
- Vous pourriez faire attention, non ?

Cependant, si l'on veut signifier à la personne qui s'excuse que l'on n'est pas véritablement offensé par l'action dont elle s'excuse on peut être indulgent et utiliser diverses répliques plus ou moins courantes qui le montrent  ;

- C(e n)'est pas grave.
- C(e n)'est rien.
- N'en faites pas cas.
- Il n'y a pas de mal.
- C(e n)'est pas la peine(, c'est rien).
- Ça va
- N'y pensez pas, ce n'est rien.
- Je vous en prie.
- Pas de problème.
- Pas besoin de vous excuser, ce sont des choses qui arrivent.

Comment: Merci pour votre aide.